# jQuery droppable DOM event order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-droppable

I have two listeners. One is the droppable class from jquery UI

```
$("#myDiv").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         console.log('I happened');
         if (window.draggingMove == true) {
              alert('I want to get here but I never make it');
         }
    }
});
```

I also have a higher up listener that clears things universally.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(event) {
    window.draggingMove = false;
    console.log('all dragging is cleared');
});
```

However, when I complete the "drop" action and they both trigger, yet the second one triggers first, so i see this in my console.

```
  "all dragging is cleared"
  "I happened"
```

It was my understanding that droppable should trigger first since its attached to myDiv. How can I get that to happen before document listener?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, the order of UI drop events should be more clearly documented....

Answer (score 0):

I think, $(document) is for the universal, so it will happen at every mouseup event not only the drop. If there is an mouseup event happen before drop happen, it should be called first.